# Unicode character variable causes SyntaxError

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, unicode, python-3.6

I have a unicode python file, with one some source code in unicode:

```
ξ = inp
```

The file has this header:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

This runs perfectly on my laptop,
But when I try to run this in a docker container, I get an error:

```
    ξ = inp
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Side question, why would you bind 'ξ' to `input`?

Comment: To stay similar to the original equation

Comment: Yeah, but are you sure you want to assign it to the `input` object, not the return value?

Comment: There is a variable named `input` in scope if that is what you mean

Comment: That's all, thanks.

Comment: That sounds like you're not actually on Python 3.

Comment: Wow true, docker's on `2.7`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your docker is configured to run the code with python 2. Adding `#!/usr/bin/env python3` won't be enough because docker doesn't use this shebang to determine the python version used to execute the code.